# FancyBox - Open gallery from button

Tags: fancybox

Using fancyBox, I want to open an images gallery clicking on a single button. This is clearly detailed on the site but it doesn't work?! I am not an expert and maybe I am doing something wrong. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="image1.jpg">BUTTON</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'image1.jpg',
        title : '1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'image2.jpg',                
        title : '2nd title'
    },
], {
    padding : 0
});
return false;
});
```

External resources used: jquery.fancybox.js & jquery.fancybox.css

Anyone who knows what's wrong?

Comment: exactly i dont knw also i guess plz make sure `href`

Comment: Maybe you just need to wrap your code inside the `.ready()` method http://jsfiddle.net/k9jvnp1k/